# Function to find string on page and click link next to it?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering whether it is possible to devise a script which will search a webpage for a certain string of text, and then click the link in the element id directly to its right.

Is this possible. Maybe javascript, php?

Please help, and thanks to all that do. :)

@Four_lo

Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry, maybe it's because I'm pretty new to javascript, but I can't really understand anything on the page you suggested.

I put together some javascript which will search the page for an element id and click the link within there.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(){
    var linkPage = document.getElementById('linkid').href;
    window.location.href = linkPage;
}
onload=init;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.barnsley-chronicle.co.uk" id="linkid">GO HERE</a>
<a href="test.html" id="thisone">I WANT TO CLICK HERE!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

So basically, I need to search the page for GO HERE. Then, once this is found, I need to click the link in id="thisone", if that makes sense.

The above code works, and clicks the link within the id specified. However, I'd like to find certain text within that id, then move onto the next id, and click the link within that id.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. It will probably take some finesse but here is where you should start to access String you need. I believe regular expressions will be a must as well.

http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#processinginstruction 
http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: I added some more information to my original post. Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more complicated than it needs to be:

```
function performAfterLinkWithText(text, perform) {
    // get all the links
    var $links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // scan them for your text
    for(var i in $links) {
        if($links[i].innerHTML === text) {
            var $next = $links[i] // ready for loop
                , terminateAfter = 20 // don't repeat forever
                ;
            // keep checking the adjacent element
            // because newlines show up as #text
            do {
                $next = $next.nextSibling;
            } while( !$next.href && terminateAfter-- > 0 );

            // do your thing
            perform($next.href, $next); // window.location.href = $next.href;
        }
    }
}

// test -- performAfterLinkWithText('GO HERE', function(url, link) { console.log(url, link); });

performAfterLinkWithText('GO HERE', function(url) { window.location.href = $next.href; });
```

Or with jQuery:

```
window.location.href = $('a:contains("GO HERE")').next().attr('href')
```